# Is there any benefit to Listen Carefully in the Dream World minigame Pokémon Seek?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

In Pokémon Seek, the mini-game in the Pokémon Dream World, you can Listen Carefully to see if the Pokémon is present, but the timer ticks down while you listen. However, if you click on the bush right away and it's the wrong Pokémon, you don't lose any time.

Is there any advantage to using Listen Carefully instead of just clicking the bush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature was probably created to help you identify the Pokemon in the shaking bush by it's call. Since the timer counts down while you're listening and each passing second costs you to lose 500 Points, I don't think the "Listen Carefully" feature is worth using. You can probably click 2-3 bushes in the time it takes to "Listen Carefully."

I find it easier to use the Berry location to find where the missing Pokemon is. Usually the missing Pokemon will be within 3 steps from the screen where you found the Berry.